# Why does $\mathbb{P}[X_i=j]= (\frac 1 n)^{j-1} \cdot (\frac {n-i +1} 1)$ here?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, geometric-distribution

I am asking this to understand the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) better.

Say that we are trying to collect $n$ coupons, and every time we obtain a box of cereal, we get a coupon, which has an equal probability of giving us any of the $n$ coupons. I am trying to understand why if we let $X_i$ be a random variable which returns the amount of boxes we bought until we got the $i$th new card, measured from the boxes we bought right after getting the $(i-1)$st new card, that $\mathbb{P}[X_i=j]= (\frac 1 n)^{j-1} \cdot (\frac {n-i +1} 1)$.

My chief difficulty in understanding this is that the sample points we have vary in terms of which coupons their $i$th first element and $(i-1)$st first element are, as well as which boxes it were on which we have found the $i$th first element and $(i-1)$st first element. If the question simply was, what is the probability of finding coupon $a$ on the $b$th box we have opened, and to open $j-1$ boxes after this and still get coupon $a$, and then to on the $j$th box after this to get coupon $b$, I could see that $(\frac 1 n)^{j-1} \cdot (\frac {n-i +1} 1)$ is the probability; but because these things vary on each sample point I am not seeing this.

So far, I have tried thinking that the question is essentially that given we have grabbed $i-1$ different things out of $n$ available choices, what’s the probability that for the next $j-1$ grabbings, we grab the same thing, and for the jth grabbing, grab something different? However, the matter is still rather unclear for me- even when I phrase the question like this, I am not seeing how to relate this to the sample points which vary in terms of how many boxes it took to obtain the $i$th new coupon and which coupons is the $i$th, etc. So why does  $\mathbb{P}[X_i=j]= (\frac 1 n)^{j-1} \cdot (\frac {n-i +1} 1)$ here?

Comment: Can we express the probability $P(X_i = j)$ as $P(Z_i = j | \mbox{ I have already found the coupons $j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}$})$? Where $Z_i$ is the again the number of boxes I have to open before finding the $i$-th coupon (where $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}\}$)? If so, the problem will be almost straigthforward.

Comment: @LucaOnnis and then the idea is that if we wanted $P(X_i = j)$ on the entire probability space, it is the same, because all of the ways of finding the coupons have probability which sum to one, so after we multiply this probability you gave by the probability of finding the coupons, we can factor out this and get this multiplied by something which sums to one?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand correctly, in particular I thought that $P(X_i = j)$ was more like a conditional probability (so $X_i = j$ given that we have already found the coupons $j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}$. Is it correct or I'm not understanding? :(

Comment: @lucaOnnis in the way the solution to the coupon problem sets up the r.v. $X_i$, given a specific way we have chose the boxes, each of which contain coupons, we return the amount of boxes between the $i$th distinct coupon we have found, and the $i-1$st distinct coupon we have found by choosing the boxes that way. Between different sample points in our probability space, the $i$th distinct coupon we have found could be different things- so in the event $X_i = j$, there isn't a fixed coupon which is the $i$th one, and there isn't a fixed box which we needed to open to get the $i$th one

Comment: @lucaOnnis but I think your comment allowed me to see the solution

Comment: That's great. I have tried to post my answer although it seems different from the  formula you have given. Probably I made a mistake (?), or I simply misunderstand the question. Let me know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can express the probability $P(X_i = j)$ as $P(Z_i = j | \mbox{ I have already found the coupons $j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}$})$ where $Z_i$ is again the number of boxes I have to open before finding the $i$-th coupon (where $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}\}$) the problem is almost straigthforward. In fact, define $I$ as:
$$
I = \{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}\} \implies |I| = n-i+1
$$
So the distribution of $Z_i$ given that we've already found coupons $j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}$ is geometric and in particular:
$$
P(Z_i = j | j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}) = P(Y_1\in\{j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}\})\cdots P(Y_{j-1}\in\{j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}\})P(Y_j\in I) 
$$
where $Y_k$ is the coupon we find in the $k$-th box. Finally:
$$
P(Z_i = j | j_1,\dots,j_{i-1}) = \Bigr(\frac{i-1}{n}\Bigl)^{j-1}\Bigl(\frac{n-i+1}{n}\Bigr)
$$